# Question about Eisenstein Criterion

Tags: abstract-algebra

The following is a use of eisenstein criterion that i have taken out from my lecture note.

$f(x, y) = x^4 +x^3y^2 +x^2y^3 +y$ is irreducible in Q[x, y]. This can be proved by treating Q[x,y] as (Q[y])[x] and applying the Eisenstein criterion with p = y.

However, I can't understand why i can apply eisenstein criterion this way. Why is y prime in Q[y]. How can I prove this? Thanks

Comment: One knows this in high-school, long before one learns the structural version in Andreas's answer. Namely $\ y\mid f(y)g(y) \Rightarrow\, y\mid f(y)\,$ or $\,y\mid g(y)\,$ is equivalent to $\,f(0)g(0) = 0\,\Rightarrow\, f(0)=0\,$ of $\,g(0)=0,\,$ by the Factor / Remainder Theorem. But the latter is true because the coefficient ring $\Bbb Q$ is a domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\mathbf{Q}[y]/(y) \cong \mathbf{Q}$ is a field, so that $y$ is  prime.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal generated by $y$ in the PID, $\mathbf{Q}[y]$ is maximal (hence prime) as the quotient ring is the filed of rational numbers.